# Cluster GPS Points by set Distance

Tags: arcmap

I have X,Y data that I am trying to buffer to find clusters. My definition for a cluster is " 2 or more points with a maximum distance of 200 meters".  My problem is:  Point A, Point B, and Point C included into a a single cluster.  Point A to Point B is 50m, Point A to C is 190m, but point B to C is 225 meters.  Therefore I do not believe that all points in my cluster are meeting my definition of a cluster?

Comment: That's correct: you do not have a clear definition. But what is your question?  Incidentally, [this closely related answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/14193) might already resolve your question, whatever it may be.