# I have many points (the points have elevation) I want to remove some points that are too close together

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, buffer, elevation

How can I select several points in a buffer to just each buffer them and among them to choose a point that has the highest elevation using ArcMap?

Each point can be in several buffer and as each buffer can have multiple points.

I have many points that has elevation and I want to remove some points that are too close together. WhatI would like to keep a point that has more elevation among them. what do I have to do?

[image]

Comment: You can use 'select by location' to select all the point that intersect the buffers and then 'select by attributes' to get the point with the highest elevation.

Comment: (Each point can be in several buffer and as each buffer can have multiple points)

Comment: To select the points that intersect only a particular buffer, you can just select that buffer first, and when you are using the `search by location` check the `use selected features` option to only get the points that intersect that particular buffer.

Comment: I have a lot of point I want to remove some points that are too close together and I want to keep a point that has more elevation among them. what do I have to do?

Comment: You can try to [generalize](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/9087) your points or [dissolve](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14192/is-there-a-free-aggregate-points-tool-out-there-for-arcgis-10) them.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done using a raster approach with spatial analyst.

1) Convert your point to raster using th heigth field and replace NoData values by zero with the raster calculator

2) use focal statistics (Maximum) with your preferred radius (of the size of your "buffer")

3) Extract multivalue to point

4) Select the points with the same height values than the underlying raster and you get the local maxima in your selected radius.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with a vector based approach with Advanced (ArcInfo) licence

1) generate the near table with a given search radius

2) join by attribute the NEAR_FID with the input point FID

3) use summary statistics to get the maximum height in each point neighbourhood IN_FID

4) join by attribute the FID of your input point with the result of the summary statistics

5) select the points where the height is equal to the max height

Answer (score 1):

1. Create small buffer around points
2. Dissolve buffers, no multipart. Give them unique names, statistics -max z.
3. Spatially join points to dissolved.
4. Select point with z = max z in polygon. Switch selection and delete selected